# Вывод процесса tar в процентах

Tags: вывод, архивация, tar, linux

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно выводить информацию во время архивации о состоянии в процентах.  
То есть на сколько процентов готово или количество оставшихся файлов.
У меня есть только один вариант: перед началом архивирования узнать размер будущего архива и отслеживать его размере.
Но я не знаю как узнать размер будущего архива.

Comment: Запустить второй поток, который будет подсчитывать прогресс.

Comment: @perfect, расскажите подробнее, пожалуйста, о втором потоке и как он должен работать.

Comment: гарантированно узнать размер будущего архива можно только одним способом - заархивировать и узнать. Но можно делать приблизительную оценку, зная, как жмутся разные файлы. Текст жмется хорошо, а вот видео - почти нет.

В случае tar есть аргумент `--checkpoint` который будет выводить кол-во обработанных файлов. и ещё есть `--checkpoint-action=` - выполнять нужное действие на каждый "чекпоинт" Узнать кол-во файлов в целом поможет `find . -type f | wc -l`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для отслеживания как времени, так и выполнения процесса c использованием процентов для наглядности рекомендуется использовать утилиту [pv](https://habrahabr.ru/post/65384/).
Установить можно следующим образом `apt-get install pv`,
использовать, например так:

```
# tar -cvf archive.tar * | pv -s $(du -sb | grep -o '[0-9]*') > out.tgz

81B 0:00:00 [1.54MB/s] [>                                         ]  0%
```